# How do I find the position of my Dialog Window on the desktop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am looking for "Dialog window" coordinates relative to the "desktop window" as apposed to itself?

Neither of the following do what I need. The just start at 0,0

Defines dimension of Dialog window starting at 0,0

```
HWND hWnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rectWin);
c.Format("%d  %d  %d  %d", rectWin.top, rectWin.bottom, rectWin.left, rectWin.right);
MessageBox(c);
```

Defines dimension of the Desktop window starting at 0,0

```
HWND hWnd = ::GetDesktopWindow();
::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rectWin);
c.Format("%d  %d  %d  %d", rectWin.top, rectWin.bottom, rectWin.left, rectWin.right);
MessageBox(c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/11570